# symfony2 can't setFlash message

Tags: php, session, symfony

I can't do this in my normal controller:

```
$this->setFlash('settings_successfully_uploaded', 'settings.upload.successfully');
```

I googled solution to do it like this:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('add_remove_friend', $flashMessageText);
```

But I would like to know why I can't setFlash directly? Because in my another controller which seems to be similiar nothing special I using there I can do it directly... So .. what's the problem? And the second controller is overriden `FOSProfileController`.

Comment: This is simply the new API. No problems here.

Comment: sorry squazic how u meaned it please?

Comment: The proper way to set a flash message is the second piece of code you pasted. Something like the first way worked in 2.0, but they have since deprecated that API

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33634456/1374947) should probably help on resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 2.0, the API was to use `$this->setFlash`, as you have in your first code snippet. Per discussion [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1863) and related, linked issues, it was decided that this key/value pair was not a good idea.

The solution manifested itself in the new API, `$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()`, you mentioned in your second code snippet. The new API allows for more flexibility. See the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#session).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that second controller is overridden FOSProfileController? Not extend? 
I suppose that you are calling parent method during call $this->setFlash(). In other FOS bundle I saw implementation of setFlash() method.

Please check patent class.