# Issue with undefined session "setFlash" - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

i'm working through a [tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-vos-applications-web-avec-symfony2/manipulez-vos-nouveaux-jouets) on Symfony2 (im a newbie on PHP) and i'm having difficulty displaying a flash  message from the *Session* Object.
Below my *Controller* code

```html
<?php

namespace tuto\WelcomeBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class HomepageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'Bienvenue à toi '.$this->get('session')->get('user_name').' !');
        return $this->render('tutoWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig');
    }
    public function whoAmIAction($name)
    {
        # get the session
        $session = $this->get('session');
        # store the user'name in the session
        $session->set('user_name', $name);
        return $this->redirect($this->container->get('router')->generate('tutoWelcomeBundle_homepage'));
    }
}
```

The `setFlash('notice', 'Bienvenue à toi '.$this->get('session')->get('user_name').' !')` is returning an '*undefined method error*' .
I did try to declare it in the AppKernel.php as part of the bundles but the namespace *Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session* is not found.
Below the layout rendering it

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}" title="Retour à l'accueil">Tutoriel Symfony2</a>
    Bonjour et bienvenue dans ce tutoriel pour Symfony2</p>
    <p>
      {% for key, flash in app.session.getFlashes()%} {%if flash%} {{flash}} {%endif%} {%endfor%}
    </p>
  </header>

  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
```

Platform Info
WAMP 2.5
Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:  `$session->addFlash` and `$session->setFlash` do not exist in SF 2

To set a flash message from the session object directly (for instance if you are not in a controller that extends SF's base one), you can use the method below

```
 $session->getFlashBag()->add('[YourType]', "[YourMessage]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already extending the FrameworkBundle's `Controller` you should have access to a method called `addFlash` which is a shortcut for adding flash messages in session.

You can lookup the definition of the method [here](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L111).

So, simply replace `$this->get('session')->setFlash` with `$this->addFlash` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.However this raise another issue at the template level  '"getFlashes" for object "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session" does not exist'

Comment: Found the solution . Change 'app.session.getFlashes()' with 'app.session.get('flashes')'

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

**[Solution]**
Based on the feedback of [Artamiel][2] (below) and the following [blog][3].
Change the `$this->get('session')->setFlash` with `$this->addFlash` in the Controller and `app.session.getFlashes()` with `app.session.get('flashes')` in the TWIG template.